# How to mark an element visually in ListView the user clicked on?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. I'd like to visually mark the list element the user clicked on by changing it's background permanently (until the user clicks on another element that is). How do I achieve that? I believe that there's a built-in feature inside LisView for this, but I had no luck finding it yet.

By default ListView animates the background color of the list-element clicked, I just want that modified color to "stay". I've already set the ListView's ChoiceMode to single choice, but it doesn't affect it visually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ListView.setSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28int%29)?